# Periodic tasks in Django are not called

Tags: python, django, cron, django-crontab

I use `django_crontab` to periodically call my tasks. The problem is that periodic tasks are not called.

I created a test function that sends me a message and I can understand that the task is done:

```py
def test_crj():
    send_message("Test cronjobs!")
```

I set it to run once every five minutes:

```py
# in settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ... ,
    "django_crontab",
]
CRONJOBS = [
    ("*/5 * * * *", "project.cronjob.test_crj", '>> /tmp/test.log'),
]
```

`crontab` sees it:

```bash
> docker exec container python3.9 manage.py crontab show
# Currently active jobs in crontab:
# a35573388f4e46c33f88fc825f0a1d8f -> ('*/5 * * * *', 'project.cronjob.test_crj', '>> /tmp/test.log')

> docker exec container crontab -l
# */5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /app/manage.py crontab run a35573388f4e46c33f88fc825f0a1d8f >> /tmp/test.log # django-cronjobs for project
```

But nothing happens!
Meanwhile, when I run the function independently, everything works fine.
And when I run it the way the system `crontab` should run (as I understand it), it works too.

```bash
> docker exec container python3.9 manage.py crontab run a35573388f4e46c33f88fc825f0a1d8f
# it works
```

What could be the error and who is to blame - `django_crontab` or the system `crontab`? Or where and how do I look at the logs, why it doesn't work?